# How to get exactly same text renderd in textarea and span?

Tags: html, css, fonts, textarea

I need to render exactly same text (width,height,font, fontfamily ...) 
in  `<textarea>` and `<span>` element, some thing like [same text in `<input>` and `<div>`](http://jsfiddle.net/zbhyxdot/), but copying  every style about font from `<textarea>` to `<span>` does not help. Help me please.

Comment: Pretty much the same as the post you linked, except textarea instead of input. What's going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, copying `"inherit"` does not mean copying real value (as their parent may have different values for that property). This is my fault!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about same ui part, you can create one class with all the different properties and assign to both span and div.

Answer (score 0):

Create a style rule using CSS:

```
<style>

input, div {
    /* insert styles here */
}


</style>
```